# How to find union and intersection of events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have sample space of experiment $S=\left\{x|-\infty<x<\infty\right\}$. I  consider events 
$$A_i=\left\{x \;\middle|\;\frac{1}{2^{i-1}}\le x<\frac{3}{2^i}\right\};i=1,2...$$

And I want to determine  $\ \  \bigcup_{i}^{\infty}A_i$ and $\bigcap_{i}^{\infty}A_i$.

I started with intersection, I tried to "draw" it by visualizing intervals on a line, I found that both ends are moving toward zero. So I concluded:

$$\bigcap_{i}^{\infty}=\emptyset$$

I had more problems with the union, after visualizing I found that there are actually "gaps" between intervals (eg. between $A_1$ and $A_2$ and so on...). So what do I do with this union? And as for the intersection, do you think it is necessary to formalize it more?

PS:I wasn't sure how to tag this question, so a retag might be needed...

Comment: For the intersection I'd note $A_2 \cap A_3 = \emptyset$, hence $\bigcap A_i = \emptyset$. You can rewrite the union as $\bigcup_i \big[\frac{2}{2^i}, \frac{3}{2^i}\big]$.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion